# Support of Radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading Folland's Real Analysis. The following is the exercise 7.2.b.

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space with a Radon measure $\mu$. Show $x\in\text{supp}(\mu)$ iff $\int f \text {d}\mu >0$ for every $f\in C_c(X, [0,1]) $ such that $f (x)>0.$

The support of a Radon measure is defined as the minimal closed set of full measure(the complement of the union of all open sets with zero measure). I proved $\rightarrow $, but the converse seems harder. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Contrapositive; if $x\notin \operatorname{supp} \mu$, then there is an $f\in C_c(X)$ with $f(x) > 0$ and $\int f\,d\mu = 0$.

Comment: How can I construct such a continuous function or prove the existence? I can find a simple function $f$ with $f (x)>0$ and $\int fd\mu =0$ easily, but I have no idea on continuous functions..

Comment: Do you recall Urysohn's lemma?

Comment: Ah.. thanks! LCH spaces are T3.5 spaces.